# stack vs buffer

Tags: operating-system, terminology

What is the difference between buffer and stack? Is a buffer overflow and stack overflow the same thing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

A stack overflow is usually caused by unbridled recursion (although it can be caused in the normal course of events if you don't have enough stack space for a normal level of function calls, such as with embedded systems, or even with limited recursion if the limits are too high). An example below:

```
void f (void) {
    f();
}
int main (void) {
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

In that example, the `f()` function very foolishly calls itself and, each time it does that, it allocates a stack frame, which will eventually lead to an overflow of the stack.

A buffer overflow, on the other hand, is caused by writing beyond the end of a buffer. They're often confused since a buffer overflow on the stack will often corrupt the stack but, technically, they're very different things. An example of stack-based buffer overflow is:

```
void f (void) {
    char str[10];
    strcpy (str, "This is far too long to fit");
}
```

This will probably corrupt the stack since you're trying to shove a 27-character string (28 bytes) into a space that's only 10 bytes in size.

But a buffer overflow doesn't necessarily have to be on the stack. If the buffer was allocated from the heap (say, with `malloc`), there's a good chance it will trash the memory arena instead, as per:

```
void f (void) {
    char *blk = malloc (10);
    if (blk != 0) {
        memset (blk, ' ', 100);
        free (blk);
    }
}
```

Similar to the previous example except the buffer overflow is not corrupting the stack. Rather it's writing beyond the end of the buffer in the heap.

Answer (score 2):

A buffer overflow is when you aren't checking the length of a buffer, or pass a non-terminated buffer to a function expecting one (specifically in C). You go past the end of the allocated buffer.

Buffer overflow:

```
char *foo = malloc(10); /* 10 bytes in our buffer */
char bar[] = "This is way bigger than 10 bytes"; 
strcpy(foo, bar);
```

A Stack overflow is when you use up all the stack memory. This is called by recursion, allocating too maky things on the stack.

Stack overflow:

```
int foo()
{
    int bar = 4;
    foo();
    return 1; /* we never get here, silly */
}
```